# Prevent Remix from recompiling in real time?

Tags: solidity, remix, solc

How do I prevent online Solidity Compiler called "Remix" from recompiling my code real-time?

When using features like Oraclize, the recompilation takes long and happens all the time, making the overall IDE non responsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turn off `Auto Compile` in the `Settings` section:

[image]